# Simplify Massive Match Case - Scala

Tags: scala, switch-statement, pattern-matching, refactoring, match

So in one of the places we have this huge `variable match case` statement.

Containing almost 150 distinct `case` statements

Looks horrible.

I want to break it up into smaller functions, I can group the matches into say 10 pieces and then the number `case` statements come down to around 15. Which is fine.

It currently looks like this

```
massiveCaseVariable match {
  case "one" => 1
  case "two" => 2
  case "three" => 3
  case "four" => 4
  case "five" => 5
  case "six" => 6
}
```

But I don't want to do it like this

```
massiveCaseVariable match {
  case "one" || "two" || "three" => firstCategory(massiveCaseVariable)
  case "four" || "five" || "six" => secondCategory(massiveCaseVariable)
}

def firstCategory(caseVariable: String): Int =
  caseVariable match {
    case "one"   => 1
    case "two"   => 2
    case "three" => 3
  }

def secondCategory(caseVariable: String): Int =
  caseVariable match {
    case "four" => 4
    case "five" => 5
    case "six"  => 6
  }
```

It's too repetitive. Is there a better more concise way to do this?

I'm on Scala 2.11

PS: The examples are for illustration purposes only. I'm definitely not trying to match Strings to Integers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to simply combine you matches then you can notice that these are actually partial functions (because matching can fail):

```
val firstCategory: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
    case "one"   => 1
    case "two"   => 2
    case "three" => 3
  }

val secondCategory: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
    case "four" => 4
    case "five" => 5
    case "six"  => 6
  }
```

which can be combined:

```
val all = firstCategory orElse secondCategory
all("one")
```

Interestingly many collections are partial functions e.g. `Map`, so:

```
val firstCategory = Map[String, Int](
    "one"   -> 1,
    "two"   -> 2,
    "three" -> 3
  )

val secondCategory = Map[String, Int](
    "four" -> 4,
    "five" -> 5,
    "six"  -> 6
  )

val all = firstCategory ++ secondCategory
all("one")
```

should work the same way in this example.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer as this answers my question exactly. In fact I refactored the `match case` using the `PartialFunction` with `orElse` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use extractor objects hiding some logic in `unapply` methods. It's hard to answer better without your actual code. Can you share couple of your actual `case`s describing their "repetitive" nature?

https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

```
  trait Hierarchy

  class Case1(val s: String) extends Hierarchy

  object Case1 {
    def unapply(arg: Case1): Boolean = arg.s == "one" || arg.s == "two"
  }

  class Case2(val s: String) extends Hierarchy

  object Case2 {
    def unapply(arg: Case2): Boolean = arg.s == "three" || arg.s == "four" || arg.s == "five"
  }

  class Case3(val s: String) extends Hierarchy

  object Case3 {
    def unapply(arg: Case3): Option[String] = if (arg.s == "six" || arg.s == "seven") Some(arg.s) else None
  }

  class Case4(val s: String) extends Hierarchy

  object Case4 {
    // some other logic
    def unapply(arg: Case4): Option[(String, Int)] = if (arg.s == "eight") Some(arg.s, 8) 
                                                     else if (arg.s == "nine") Some(arg.s, 9) 
                                                     else None
  }

  val massiveCaseVariable: Hierarchy = ???

  massiveCaseVariable match {
    case Case1() => ???
    case Case2() => ???
    case Case3(s) => ???
    case Case4(s, n) => ???
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pattern matching then, or at least not by itself.

```
trait Handler {
def canHandle(variable: String): Boolean
def handle(variable: String): Int
}
class HandlerCategory1 extends Handler {/*...*/}
class HandlerCategory2 extends Handler {/*...*/}
// ...

val variable: String = ???
val handlers = List(new HandlerCategory1(), new HandlerCategory2())

handlers.find(_.canHandle(variable)).map(_.handle(variable))
```

You can put your condition from pattern matching into specific `canHandle()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize it in following way

```
  val all = firstCategory() ++ secondCategory()

  all("some").apply()

  def firstCategory() : Map[String, () => ()] = {
    Map(
      "first" -> (() => {}),
      "second" -> (() => {})
    )
  }
  def secondCategory(): Map[String, () => ()] = {
    Map(
      "third" -> (() => {
        print("some code")
      }),
      "forth" -> (() => {
        print("some other code")
      })
    )
  }
```